# Is it possible to scrape prometheus endpoints running on the same machine and push them to a pushgateway at a static IP?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I have a system where instances can be added at any time. Metric collection becomes difficult since its hard to gather updated information on all the scrape targets. I wanted to use a pushgateway at a static IP to ingest the metrics from all instances.

Unfortunatey the service running on these instances only offers a prometheus scrape endpoint (pull). Is it possible for me to add a second service that can scrape the first one (locally) and push the metrics to the pushgateway at the static IP? This second service would act purely as a forwarder.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question, but maybe the pushgateway option can be a solution ? Have a look at https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I do have a pushgateway running at a static IP. The service which I want to get metrics from only has a scrape endpoint though, I wanted to see if there was something I can run that scrapes the endpoint(locally) and pushes the metrics to a pushgateway.
The main reason for this is that my services change IPs often and I want to avoid manually updating the scrape config on the metric server.